# Apache won't start after creating symbolic link

Tags: permissions, fedora, apache-http-server, localhost

I'm installing Apache for the first time and trying to display some webpages on localhost.

Apache's default path for serving web pages is `/var/www/html/` but I don't have permissions to write there. Rather than change ownership of the entire directory, I decided to get rid of the `/html/` folder in `/var/www/` and created it in my home directory.

Then I made a symbolic link `ln -s /home/me/html/ /var/www/` hoping Apache would serve web pages from my home directory while keeping the default path, and following the symbolic link to my home directory.

When I go to start the Apache service with `service httpd start` I get `Job failed. See system journal and 'systemctl status' for details.`

Comment: I fixed my own problem, all I had to do was chown it. I don't know how to delete my post so I'll leave it at this.

Comment: Congrats on finding a solution!  Actually, you should add your solution as an answer below.  You'll then be able to "accept" it in a day or two (waiting period).  It may help someone else in the future :)